# Face aligment check with DLIB

Tags: opencv, dlib

I am just wondering is it possible to detect is the face aligned correctly, straight to the camera with DLIB and OpenCV?

[image]

I tried this code to detect shape and get the points of face:

[image]

```
detector = dlib.get_frontal_face_detector()
predictor = dlib.shape_predictor(args["shape_predictor"])

vs = VideoStream(0).start()

    while True:
        # grab the frame from the threaded video stream, resize it to
        # have a maximum width of 400 pixels, and convert it to
        # grayscale
        frame = vs.read()
        frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=400)
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        # detect faces in the grayscale frame
        rects = detector(gray, 0)

        # loop over the face detections
        for rect in rects:
            # determine the facial landmarks for the face region, then
            # convert the facial landmark (x, y)-coordinates to a NumPy
            # array
            shape = predictor(gray, rect)
            shape = face_utils.shape_to_np(shape)

            # loop over the (x, y)-coordinates for the facial landmarks
            # and draw them on the image
            for (x, y) in shape:
                print x,y
                cv2.circle(frame, (x, y), 1, (0, 0, 255), -1)
            cv2.putText(frame, "Aptiktas veidas", (10, 30),
                cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (0, 0, 255), 2)

        # show the frame
        cv2.imshow("Frame", frame)
        key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
```

Comment: Updated a question with a code and picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Below is a function I wrote to find the pose where the person head is facing. here p1 and p2 define the vector of pose. Calculating the angle between them is trivial and based on angle you may decide which image to accept or discard.

```
def pose_estimate(image, landmarks):
    """
    Given an image and a set of facial landmarks generates the direction of pose
    """
    size = image.shape
    image_points = np.array([
        (landmarks[33, 0], landmarks[33, 1]),     # Nose tip
        (landmarks[8, 0], landmarks[8, 1]),       # Chin
        (landmarks[36, 0], landmarks[36, 1]),     # Left eye left corner
        (landmarks[45, 0], landmarks[45, 1]),     # Right eye right corner
        (landmarks[48, 0], landmarks[48, 1]),     # Left Mouth corner
        (landmarks[54, 0], landmarks[54, 1])      # Right mouth corner
        ], dtype="double")

    model_points = np.array([
        (0.0, 0.0, 0.0),             # Nose tip
        (0.0, -330.0, -65.0),        # Chin
        (-225.0, 170.0, -135.0),     # Left eye left corner
        (225.0, 170.0, -135.0),      # Right eye right corner
        (-150.0, -150.0, -125.0),    # Left Mouth corner
        (150.0, -150.0, -125.0)      # Right mouth corner
        ])

    focal_length = size[1]
    center = (size[1]/2, size[0]/2)
    camera_matrix = np.array([
        [focal_length, 0, center[0]],
        [0, focal_length, center[1]],
        [0, 0, 1]
        ], dtype="double")

    dist_coeffs = np.zeros((4, 1))
    success, rotation_vector, translation_vector = cv2.solvePnP(model_points, image_points, camera_matrix, dist_coeffs)     
    (nose_end_point2D, jacobian) = cv2.projectPoints(np.array([(0.0, 0.0, 1000.0)]), rotation_vector, translation_vector, camera_matrix, dist_coeffs)
    p1 = (int(image_points[0][0]), int(image_points[0][1]))
    p2 = (int(nose_end_point2D[0][0][0]), int(nose_end_point2D[0][0][1]))
    return p1, p2
```

Comment: my language is Java so i ask this  question , what you do exactly you stitch face to get  a face in front and strait position after that do dlib on the e corrected face ?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the points from dlib and use it in opencv.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from facial_landmarks import calc_points
import sys 

# Read Image
im = cv2.imread('img.jpg')
if im is None:
    print('Image not found')
    sys.exit()
size = im.shape

facial_points = calc_points('img.jpg')
if len(facial_points) == 0:
    print('Face not Detected')
    sys.exit()

cl = cr = 0

for i in range(len(facial_points)):
    #2D image points. If you change the image, you need to change vector
    image_points = np.array([
                                facial_points[i]['nose'],     # Nose tip
                                facial_points[i]['chin'],     # Chin
                                facial_points[i]['lefteye'],     # Left eye left corner
                                facial_points[i]['righteye'],     # Right eye right corne
                                facial_points[i]['leftmouth'],     # Left Mouth corner
                                facial_points[i]['rightmouth']      # Right mouth corner
    ], dtype='double')

    # 3D model points.
    model_points = np.array([
                                (0.0, 0.0, 0.0),             # Nose tip
                                (0.0, -330.0, -65.0),        # Chin
                                (-225.0, 170.0, -135.0),     # Left eye left corner
                                (225.0, 170.0, -135.0),      # Right eye right corne
                                (-150.0, -150.0, -125.0),    # Left Mouth corner
                                (150.0, -150.0, -125.0)      # Right mouth corner

                            ])


    # Camera internals

    focal_length = size[1]
    center = (size[1]/2, size[0]/2)
    camera_matrix = np.array(
                            [[focal_length, 0, center[0]],
                            [0, focal_length, center[1]],
                            [0, 0, 1]], dtype = 'double'
                            )

    dist_coeffs = np.zeros((4,1)) # Assuming no lens distortion
    (success, rotation_vector, translation_vector) = cv2.solvePnP(model_points, image_points, camera_matrix, dist_coeffs, flags=cv2.SOLVEPNP_ITERATIVE)

    (nose_end_point2D, jacobian) = cv2.projectPoints(np.array([(0.0, 0.0, 1000.0)]), rotation_vector, translation_vector, camera_matrix, dist_coeffs)

    for p in image_points:
        cv2.circle(im, (int(p[0]), int(p[1])), 3, (0,0,255), -1)


    p1 = ( int(image_points[0][0]), int(image_points[0][1]))
    p2 = ( int(nose_end_point2D[0][0][0]), int(nose_end_point2D[0][0][1]))

    cv2.line(im, p1, p2, (255,0,0), 2)

    if p1[0] > p2[0]:
        cl += 1
    else:
        cr += 1

if cl > cr:
    text = 'left'
else:
    text = 'right'
# Display image
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
cv2.putText(im, text,(10,50), font, 0.5,(0,0,255),1,cv2.LINE_AA)
cv2.imshow('Output', im)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

I wrote this code to determine if the person is turning left or right.